# Kubectl apply and set image in the same time

Tags: kubectl

I want to apply a folder which contains some yaml file and also to change the image which is used in a deployment. Is it possible to do something like:

`kubectl apply -k ./folder set image xxx -n namespace`

Comment: I think its natively supported, you may need to use something like `find ./folder  -type f -exec sed 's/image:.*/image: xxx/g' {} + |kubectl create  -f -`. this is not a working command, just a pointer

Comment: does that answer your question or you need more help? P..'s solution is working and  absolutely applicable in your case.  there is no possibility to do that using `kubectl` arguments only. sed, awk , etc